# VBA create unique ID numbers for new data in dataset

Tags: vba, dataset

I’m trying to fill down id numbers in column A for new data in dataset that resides in columns B:AB

The dataset has existing data (that already have a unique id) to which new data is added in columns B:AB.

Issue: In column A I want to add a unique_id #, where the uniqe_id= cell above +1

The data already in the dataset I'm using column C as my base to determine the last cell with data.
I'm using column A as my base to determine the first cell without data.

My code:

```
Sub Copy_ID_Down()
With Sheets("data_output").Columns("A")

Dim LastPopulatedRow As Long
Dim FirstPopulatedRow As Long
Dim ColA AS Range 

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

LastPopulatedRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
FirstPopulatedRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row


Set ColA = Range(“A” & FirstPopulatedRow & LastPopulatedRow)

ColA.Select

With Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
.Value = .Value

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End With
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Set ColA = Range(“A” & FirstPopulatedRow & LastPopulatedRow) ... not sure that is doing what you intend?

Comment: Maybe you want ...Range("A" & FirstPopulatedRow & ":A" & LastPopulatedRow) ?